# How to use an alternative JDBC pool implementation in JBoss

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, jboss6.x

We have discovered a rather very nasty leak in JBoss 6.1's JDBC pool.

This is caused by code relying on the `close` method on the connection to close underlying statements.

Although the **WrappedConnection** does close them, the code looks like [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.jbossas/jboss-as-connector/6.1.0.Final/org/jboss/resource/adapter/jdbc/WrappedConnection.java#133):

```
if (statements != null) {
  for (Iterator
       <Map.Entry<WrappedStatement, Throwable>> i=statements.entrySet().iterator(); 
       i.hasNext(); )
  {
     Map.Entry<WrappedStatement, Throwable> entry = i.next(); 
     WrappedStatement ws= entry.getKey();
     if (trackStatements==BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.TRACK_STATEMENTS_TRUE_INT)
     {
       Throwable stackTrace = entry.getValue();
       log.warn("Closing a statement you left open, please do your own housekeeping",
                 stackTrace);
     }
     try
     {
       ws.internalClose();
     }
     catch (Throwable t)
     {
       log.warn("Exception trying to close statement:", t);
     }
   }
 }
```

The statements object never removes the statements from its map, and the map grows, and grows, and those statements hold result sets, etc. (at least in the JDBC driver I'm using).

I'm wondering if anyone ever replaced the jdbc pool in JBoss with an alternative implementation that is more robust than this?

---

As a small addendum to this, the code and behavior is the same with result sets (essentially copy and paste), although the memory leak may not be significant if you don't hold on to the statement for any length of time (unlike the connection which lives in the pool by design).

Comment: Which class and version is this? Curious to know.

Comment: @ChinBoon It's org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection. That is from version 6.1.0 final, but I found it to be the same at least going back to 5.0.0

Comment: Probably that is possible but it does not seem documented. So unwrap JBoss sources ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss deploys its connection pooling for datasource as a resource adapter RAR. By default, there are two available `jboss-local-jdbc.rar` and `jboss-xa-jdbc.rar` in `deploy` folder. Connection factory and wrapper to use are declared in `META-INF/ra.xml`

So the option is to replace one or both of these resource adapters according to your declared datasource. But the implementation has to support resource enlistment into transaction with JTS and also security checks.

Not a so easy job and you will probably be the first guy to do it.

Comment: Thanks, this does get to the root of where to look. As I wrote, we aren't in need of this as we changed our code, but sounds just a bit worse than upgrading to JBoss 7.

Comment: Not sure JBoss 7 will change anything. WrappedConnection moved from common/lib/jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar to modules/org/jboss/ironjacamar/jdbcadapters/main/ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.3.Final.jar but probably most of the code remains... And I found no documentation (yet) about using DBCP or C0P3 as connection pool in JBoss 6.x or 7.x.

Comment: Thanks Yves, but they did fix it in 7 here (which is called from the close method on that class): http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.ironjacamar/ironjacamar-jdbc/1.0.7.Final/org/jboss/jca/adapters/jdbc/BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java#BaseWrapperManagedConnection.closeHandle%28org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection%29

Comment: So it seems easier to patch the class in JBoss 6.1 than trying to use an alternate pool.

Answer (score 4):

The failure to close underlying statements isn't a JBOSS pooling leak.  I believe the blame would lie with the JDBC driver implementation from your database vendor.  If I recall correctly, it's well known that Oracle's driver did not close underlying resources when the connection was closed (at least that was true back in 2006).  I don't know if it's been corrected.

http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=41036

The responsibility is *always* yours.

It's recommended that you close all ResultSet and Statement instances in a finally block, wrapped individually in try/catch blocks, in reverse order of creation.

If that's correct, and you agree, then changing pool implementation will not be sufficient.  You'll have to go through your code and do it yourself.  If you've been smart and designed in a clean persistence tier it should be relatively easy.

Sorry for not reading your code earlier.  I don't know why you're putting `Statement` in a `Map`, especially one that's not a `WeakHashMap`.  My advice would be to keep all `Statement` and `ResultSet` instances tightly bound inside a persistence tier.  Create and close them in method scope; no caching.

If you were to profile the code, I think you'd find that there's no savings to be had here.  None of those classes are thread safe, so hanging onto them could cause some rather nasty bugs.  Your app will be far more scalable, too.

Comment: Well, it is against the JDBC spec, so I don't agree it is strictly a coding problem. In this case we are using Microsoft's JDBC driver, and we haven't observed that misbehavior in the underlying JDBC driver.

Comment: It's a problem if the implementer does not follow the spec.  And I cited Oracle, not Microsoft: http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=41036.  Shout out to Brooklyn, NY - my oldest daughter lives there now.

Comment: thanks, brooklyn's great. Actually, the code isn't mine, it is what is inside JBoss' implementation. I guess I'm saying I'm not sure, in the context of my project, that I can say that people won't follow the spec and will follow instead the defensive way of programming because third party tools don't follow the spec. Either way, it seems like just a matter of registering something else in JNDI to have an alternate pool. Just curious if someone else solved that problem already.